# How can I add a database name in airflow connections when I have an instance of databases

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, airflow

I am using airflow to make some treatments and save data on a Google Cloud SQL instance that contains multiple databases. So I added a connection in airflow and I can't find where I should put the database name. Because of this issue, I cannot create an sqlalchemy engine in my python code to be able to save results.

I have done something very weird that works : get_uri and replace the "None" name by a real name of a database and then call `create_engine`.
However I don't think it is a good solution.

Could someone tell me where I should put the database name (in the connection or in the code) to make it work properly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which connection type are you using?

Comment: I am using a MySQL connection

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question then; if you put the database name in the Schema field in Airflow, it works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, database name goes into [`schema`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/connection.py#L60) field.

---

Meanwhile, picking [`conn_type="MySql"`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/connection.py#L81) shouldn't pose any problem as long as return value of [`get_uri(..)`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8f41eb75ad33a7edfeb2414d905e9b51fff3732a/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L63) function is valid